# Access office 365 authentication popup of PowerShell from Windows Form/WPF

Tags: wpf, powershell, c#-4.0, popup, runspace

I have a following PowerShell script, this scripts connects to my Azure Analysis services. As I execute following script, it opens a popup like image below.

```
param(
    [String]
    $envName1
)

$loadInfo1 = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server1 = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server1.Connect($envName1)
return $server1
```

[image]

Problem is that I want to execute this PowerShell from my WPF application. I don't understand, how can I access this Popup in my WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean by that. However, you need an account to connect to Azure, maybe you signed out or never actually signed in to Visual Studio.

Edit: I finally understand what you mean (slightly). So there are basically two solutions. First one is Azure AD. To connect to Office 355 with PowerShell using the AzureAD module, you’ll first need to install it. You can do so by running Install-Module AzureAD from an administrative PowerShell session. Once you have the module installed, run the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet. Once you do, PowerShell will prompt for your Microsoft ID and password (Work or school account). Once authenticated, you’ll be able to use all of the commands in the module.

Connecting to Office 365 with the MSOnline Module:
Connecting to Office 365 with PowerShell using the MSOnline module requires a little bit more effort. Assuming you have the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW software package installed:

Install the MSOnline module from the PowerShell Gallery by running from an administrative PowerShell console:

Install-Module MSOnline (Function)

Once the module is installed, run Get-Module to ensure PowerShell can find the module.

[image]

Finally, run the Connect-MsolService cmdlet to authenticate to Azure AD. This will prompt you for your Office 365 credential.

Comment: Hey Preyansh0605, Actually this is the requirement of my customer, he can use the same plain PowerShell and whenever popup comes he authenticate, but now he wants that popup in the .net application because he wants the same PowerShell in the background. I hope now that make you understand.

Comment: Oh! I think I understand what you mean, but I'm still not too sure. Please forgive me if this isn't the right answer, I'll try and find a solution and if it doesn't work, I'll try and find another one until I find the correct answer.

Comment: I am copying the last line of your answer. "This will prompt you for your Office 365 credential". I want this popup should come in my .net application with running the same PowerShell in the backgroud.

Comment: Oh, I don't mind if you copy any of my answers! It doesn't really make a difference to me. Anyways, let me know if it worked and glad I helped.

Comment: Hey Preyansh0605, I really appreciate your effort to understand my problem and come with a gist/idea/solution. Unfortunately, Your answer didn't help me at all. Your answer gave the solution if anyone is failing to connect with AzureAD using PowerShell. For me, I am able to connect with AzureAD using PowerShell, a popup comes and I authenticate it. I want the same popup should access using dot net code. Or it would be great if I can pass any kind of authentication silently from dot net code to PowerShell.